# Is it normal for an iPhone to remain in my devices list after logging out of Apple ID?

Tags: iphone

I saw two iPhones that I used to own under the my devices list on the manage Apple ID site.

I am sure that I signed out of apple ID on both the devices before I sold them.

After you sign out of an Apple ID on an iOS device, it's supposed to disappear from the my devices list on the manage Apple ID website. You are also supposed to receive the "Find my iPhone has been disabled" email when you sign out of apple ID on an iOS device, I also checked my mail and I didn't receive the "find my iPhone has been disabled" e-mail that you get when signing out of an iOS device.

Now this got me thinking that I might not have signed out of Apple ID before I sold the two of my iPhones, but I'm sure I did. I also want to add that I sold these two devices in the same month, but I sold the first one 3 weeks before the second one. Maybe this has some connection I don't know....

Has anyone here had the same thing happen to them? Is it normal for an iOS device to remain on "my devices list" after signing out of Apple ID and is it normal to not receive the "find my iPhone has been disabled" e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

I've never had devices automatically remove from my Apple ID device list – I've always removed it manually.

If you've sold the device and it still appears on either your Find My or Apple ID device list, simply remove it and you'll be all set.

Unless Find My iPhone is still updating the location, there is no cause for concern. If it is still updating, then perhaps it wasn't wiped properly.

Comment: Did you sign out of the devices through settings, you know through the Apple Id banner thats at the top of settings(in case of Iphone) ? So your saying after signing out of your apple id on your Iphone, your Iphone still appeared in the my devices list? Also did you receive the “find my has been disabled” email after signing out of your Iphone? In my case I didn’t receive this email and the Iphone remained in my devices.

Comment: I signed out using the erase all contents and settings, which does ask you to sign out. I don't recall if I received an email. But, like I said - so long as your device doesn't appear active in Find My iPhone, just remove it and you're fine.

Comment: Your device cannot magically sign back in just because it appears on your account lists.

Comment: Just to be clear, your talking about the erase all content and settings, which is located in settings > general > transfer or erase Iphone? 

Also im not saying that my device signed back in by itself. 
The main reason why I asked this question was because i wanted to know if the same thing has happened to other Iphone users. Could you do me a favor and check if you have received a “find my has been disabled” email? Because I didn’t receive this email for the Iphones that still appeared in the my devices list.

Comment: So after using the erase all content and settings, your Iphone still appeared in the “my devices list” on the manage apple id site?

Comment: Correct, I'm referring to the erase iPhone option in settings. The device still appeared in the Apple ID website device list.

Comment: What about the email? Did you receive it?

Comment: I don't see any email in my account, but I may have deleted it. But again, like I said, it doesn't matter. If your iPhone still appears in Find My iPhone just remove it. It has the same effect.